# Youtube IFrame API without cookies

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

My country is starting to apply laws about privacy and cookies.

Is there a way to use the Youtube IFrame API without storing cookies?

Answer (score 0):

This is a free script preventing iFrame cookies:

[cookies-enabler](https://github.com/nicholasruggeri/cookies-enabler/blob/master/cookies-enabler.js)

Here you get a list of free cookie law tools with features, pros and cons:

[free cookie law tools](https://github.com/lucatwiv/Free-cookie-law-tools)