# Is it possible to disable cookies for YouTube API iFrame Player

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am wondering if there is a "nocookie" option when using the API?
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Answer (score 12):

It's possible to overwrite the default host with the no-cookie domain. Example:

```
player = new YT.Player('youtubePlayer', {
    videoId : ID,
    height : '300px',
    width : '100%',
    host: 'http://www.youtube-nocookie.com',
    playerVars: {rel: 0},
    events : {
        'onReady' : onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange' : onPlayerStateChange
    }
});
```

Comment: First of all - it looks like it is working BUT in the js console it shows me this error on playback start: "XML-Verarbeitungsfehler: Kein Wurzel-Element gefunden
Adresse: https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/get_midroll_info?...." - in English no XML Root Element found --> then the Youtube URL and this modroll thing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [github code](https://github.com/nicholasruggeri/cookies-enabler/blob/master/cookies-enabler.js) you can use.

I got the reference from the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30607889/youtube-iframe-api-without-cookies)

The [free cookie law tools](https://github.com/lucatwiv/Free-cookie-law-tools) with features was also given in the post.

Another way also is to use the **`www`** version that was an answer given in the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555450/how-to-embed-youtube-videos-without-cookies).

> That is the version their automatic code generator outputs as well,
>   when you chose the extended privacy option.
>
> Looks like they removed the non-www version for some reason. (Although
>   doing that without adding an automatic redirect would be kind of a
>   weird move. Perhaps it is just a temporary problem or error.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `src` attribute for the iframe:

```
src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/video_id?.."
```